# How would I run a command line program and feed it data through stdin

Tags: erlang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Erlang Ports: Interfacing with a “wc”-like program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792376/erlang-ports-interfacing-with-a-wc-like-program)

What I've been doing is writing to a file in /tmp/ and then running os:cmd("cat /tmp/tmp.txt | myprogram"). There's got to be a better way though.

edit: this question is same but unanswered [Erlang Ports: Interfacing with a "wc"-like program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792376/erlang-ports-interfacing-with-a-wc-like-program)

This is similar but with weird answer which I don't think is better than what I've done http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/open-pipe-spawn-quot-cat-quot-how-to-close-stdin-of-cat-td2112721.html

This also has no solution http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/open-port-issue-td2103107.html

Comment: are you counting words in a file ?

Comment: There's a lot of things I want to use this for. Being able to interact with cli programs is kind of essential.

Comment: great. you guys closed it for points. and I can't put a bounty on the other persons questions.

Comment: The annoying part is it probably wouldn't have been closed if I hadn't linked to that other question in my own post. damn it all.